# How to show retrieve data from database into text field in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

it's my model code:

```
<?php

    class Books_model extends CI_Model 
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->load->database();
        }       
        public function get_restaurants()
        {
            $sql = "SELECT id, names FROM restaurants ";
            $query = $this->db->query( $sql );
            return $query->result();
        }
    }
```

controller code:

```
<?php

    class Booking_Controller extends CI_Controller
    {
        public function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('Books_model');
        }
        public function view()
        {
            $this->user_data['result']=$this->Books_model->get_restaurants();
            $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
            $this->load->view('restaurants/booking',$this->user_data);
        }
    }
```

What code I written in view file that the data show in text field?

Answer (score 0):

in the controller

```
<?php

    class Booking_Controller extends CI_Controller
    {
        public function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('Books_model');
        }
        public function view()
        {
            $data["result"]=$this->Books_model->get_restaurants();
            //$this->load->helper(array('form','url')); not needed
            $this->load->view('restaurants/booking',$data["result"]);
        }
    }
```

now in your view

```
<?php 
    // notice that CI strip the key "result" from the array $data to become a variable $result in the view
    foreach ($result as $row)
    {
    echo $row->id."<br>";
    echo $row->name."<br>";
    echo "----";
    }
    ?>
```

Note:

> there is no member like this "$this->user_data['result']" in
>   codeigniter but there is "$this->session->user_data("data_name")" if
>   you want to store some data in the session, but then, no need to pass
>   it to the view as an argument you can call the session data from the
>   view directly

Answer (score 0):

Try the following : 
In the Controller

```
class Booking_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Books_model');
    }
    public function view()
    {
        $data['results'] = $this->Books_model->get_restaurants();
        $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
        $this->load->view('restaurants/booking',$data);
    }
}
```

In the View:

```
<?php 
  foreach ($results as $result)
  {?>
    <label>Restaurant Name : </label>
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $result->names;?>" />
<?php } ?>
```